# Apache Phoenix Join Fails (Encountered exception in sub plan [0] execution)

Tags: apache, hbase, apache-phoenix

Here are the create table statements of the tables I'm testing, which was actually from [Phoenix](https://phoenix.apache.org/joins.html)

```
CREATE TABLE Test.Employee(
  Region VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  LocalID VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  Name VARCHAR,
  StartDate DATE,
  CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY(Region, LocalID))
SALT_BUCKETS = 1;

CREATE TABLE Test.Patent (
    PatentID VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    Region VARCHAR,
    LocalID VARCHAR,
    Title VARCHAR,
    Category VARCHAR,
    FileDate DATE,
    CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (PatentID))
SALT_BUCKETS=1;
```

And here is the simple join query:

```
SELECT E.Name, E.Region, P.PCount
FROM Test.Employee AS E
JOIN
    (SELECT Region, LocalID, count(*) AS PCount
     FROM Test.Patent
     WHERE FileDate >= to_date('2000-01-01')
     GROUP BY Region, LocalID) AS P
ON E.Region = P.Region AND E.LocalID = P.LocalID
```

Explain works fine and results to this:

```
PLAN
CLIENT 1-CHUNK PARALLEL 1-WAY FULL SCAN OVER TEST.EMPLOYEE
    PARALLEL INNER-JOIN TABLE 0
    DYNAMIC SERVER FILTER BY (E.REGION, E.LOCALID) IN ((P.REGION, P.LOCALID))
        CLIENT MERGE SORT
        CLIENT 1-CHUNK PARALLEL 1-WAY FULL SCAN OVER TEST.PATENT
            SERVER FILTER BY FILEDATE >= DATE '2000-01-01 00:00:00.000'
            SERVER AGGREGATE INTO DISTINCT ROWS BY [REGION, LOCALID]
```

But when I run it, I get this error:

```
Encountered exception in sub plan [0] execution.
```

Additional Details:

- I'm using phoenix-4.4.0-HBase-1.1
- Running against a stand-alone HBase-1.1.2 server
- Everything works fine except for queries involving JOINs
- Both tables contain 1 row each

Am currently stuck with this problem...

Thanks!

--------------UPDATE---------------

This works:

```
SELECT /*+ USE_SORT_MERGE_JOIN */ E.Name, E.Region, P.PCount
FROM Test.Employee AS E
JOIN
    (SELECT Region, LocalID, count(*) AS PCount
     FROM Test.Patent
     WHERE FileDate >= to_date('2000-01-01')
     GROUP BY Region, LocalID) AS P
ON E.Region = P.Region AND E.LocalID = P.LocalID
```

So when forced to use Sort-Merge Join, the query works, I assume there is a problem with Hash Join in my setup. Still don't have an answer.

Comment: Upon using sqlline.py, was able to catch the error:        `java.io.IOException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/iq80/snappy/CorruptionException
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.ServerCachingEndpointImpl.addServerCache(ServerCachingEndpointImpl.java:78)
        at `


Just added https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.iq80.snappy/snappy/0.4 to the hbase lib directory and it solved the problem

Comment: Could you put the --------------UPDATE--------------- section as an answer, that way we could vote it up.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

SELECT /*+ USE_SORT_MERGE_JOIN */ E.Name, E.Region, P.PCount
FROM Test.Employee AS E
JOIN
(SELECT Region, LocalID, count(*) AS PCount
FROM Test.Patent
WHERE FileDate >= to_date('2000-01-01')
GROUP BY Region, LocalID) AS P
ON E.Region = P.Region AND E.LocalID = P.LocalID
So when forced to use Sort-Merge Join, the query works, I assume there is a problem with Hash Join in my setup. Still don't have an answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).